# What is the @"name" of a UIImageView Image that was uploaded via UIImage Picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a situation where i'm using

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
```

This works fine for what I want to do, however I want to be able to upload an image via **UIImagePicker**. Then i want to be able to change the @"image", which is an actual image, whereas I want it to be the name of the uploaded image.

I've seen a few options, however I want to know how to get the exact result for a **UIImage** name so that it will appear similarly to

```
imageNamed:@"image"];
```

so i can analyse the data

The line of the code is:

```
[[LQNetworkManager sharedManager] contentFilteringAnalysis:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error)
```

Comment: you want the name of the image inside a given imageview?

Comment: yeah so I can use it in the line `imageNamed:@"UIImagePicker"`
But i'd like it to change as I upload different images

Comment: The name passed to `imageNamed:` is the name of a file on your app's resource bundle. It's just one possible way to get a `UIImage`. Once you have a `UIImage`, there is no way to get any associate file from it. The image could have been created an number of ways that don't involve a file. You really need to clarify your question.

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem possible, as pointed above that `imageName:` fetches image only in `NSBundle`, but if you pick a file from UIImagePicker doesn't come from `NSBundle`, or you can't write anything into `NSBundle`, so in your case, you might write the incoming image into `Documents/Temp Directory` and use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` to fetch.

Comment: all good i changed changed it to NSData and it did it all for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the name from **UIImageView** instead you can easily get the image by using UIImagePickerDelegate Methods

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo ;
```

And

```
    -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {

        UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [_selectPicBtn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

Hope this would help you.Thank you